# How install XFCE and remove gnome on Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS

Tags: unity, system-installation, xubuntu, xfce, thunar

Was running xUbuntu 18.0.4 LTS and upgraded (re-install via DVD) to Ubuntu 20.0.4. I'd like to get back to the XFCE Desktop as it find gnome unusable for my application. In particular I have a lot of problems with Nautilus but really liked Thunar.  These are the File Manager programs.

I attempted to install it (xfce) following an article on Linuxconfig.org which gave the following procedure:

> sudo apt install tasksel

> sudo tasksel install xubuntu-desktop

This may or may not have installed xfce but it mentions there is then some step to select the desktop to use. Unfortunately I can find no selector anywhere nor do I wish to have go thru the selection process every time I reboot.  I am still running "Files" (aka Nautilus) as an app.

Is there any way I can install the XFCE making my system xUbuntu and remove gnome or as much of gnome as is possible? Of course this pertains to Focal Fossa: i.e. Ubuntu 20.0.4. If I have to I can do a new install presuming I can find a xUbuntu 20.0.4 release.

Comment: You can install thunar simply with the command `sudo apt install thunar`.

Comment: At the DM (display manager) or greeter, or login screen you select which you want to use. During installation of `xubuntu-desktop` I would have expected you to be asked a question as to which DM you wish to use (`ubuntu-desktop` uses `gdm3` as the greeter & DM, Xubuntu does not) which will impact how it's selected. The selection is **not** when you boot, but when you enter your username & password.  I suspect you've got all you need, just haven't found out where the selector is on your greeter (which varies on what you selected at a prompt in your second listed command).

Comment: I would suggest that you instead install Xubuntu which is the official flavor of Ubuntu that includes the Xfce desktop. There's a good reason why Ubuntu releases several flavors with different desktops: it's very messy to attempt to change desktop environments on an installed system.

Comment: This is quite useful.  I may do this and burn a xUbuntu 20.0.4 DVD and reinstall from there...  I think I'm also going to order a bigger flash boot drive as mine is just 128 and I have Windows10 64 bit on it too.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* (*yy.mm*) in format for desktop & server releases (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 means the 2020-April release; no extra dot).  There are also *snap* only specialist releases which are *yy* only, but these are a different product, eg. Ubuntu Core 20 (based on the 20.04 release, with many features removed, *snap* only, ideal for device, appliance, or cloud use)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I made a DVD install of xubuntu 20.04.2 but the weirdest thing happened.  Now it prints /init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr1  no medium found    and  stdin: Not a typewriter   It repeats this line over and over again, maybe 50x   Also an Unsupported SPROM revision 11 tho that seems to have stopped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Install xfce4 desktop

   ```
   sudo apt install xfce4
   ```
2. Log out.
3. In the login screen, click your name, a gear icon will appear in the right bottom corner, click it and you can choose the desktop to use.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I can now get Thunar and see stuff.  I was required to upgrade to Flossing Fossil (20.0.4) for work but the upgrade command did'nt work.  Thus I had to burn a DVD and do a fresh install.  I may not remove Unity quite yet in case I need something for my programs to run.

Comment: Eventually when things settle down I may just try to burn a xUbuntu 20.0.4 DVD and do a clean install:  maybe after installing a bigger boot drive to my laptop.  Linux will span multiple disks with a partition so it's more forgiving than Windows in this regard.

Comment: Actually I apparently installed XFCE over Gnome so am doing a fresh install of 20.04.2 from a bootable DVD.  xubuntu20.04 is extremely buggy tho.